# Using $interval inside Angular UI Router templateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, setinterval

I'm trying to get my view template updated every 10 minutes. Using this setup in the state config doesn't work:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'landing',
    templateProvider: function($templateFactory, $interval) {
        var templateId = 0;

        return $interval(function(){
            var template = templateId % 2 == 0 ? 
                          'landing-primary.html':'landing-secondary.html';

            templateId++;

            return $templateFactory.fromUrl('views/templates/' + template);

        }, 600000);
    }
})
```

What's the best way to achieve such work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `templateProvider` option should be a function that returns an html string or a promise that resolves with an html string. It's mainly present so that you can generate html that somehow makes use of $stateParams.

What you're trying to do wouldn't normally be done through route/state definitions; what you've described is logic that should be in a directive or controller. While it's hard to say for sure without more information about exactly what you're trying to achieve, it sounds like what you really need is a single "landing" page with the content of both templates divided by an ng-switch directive that gets bound to a model property. Then in your controller you would set an $interval to change that model property every 10 minutes.

Alternatively, maybe what you want is two states, in which case the pair of states would each have in their corresponding controllers a $timeout that toggles to the other state.

Comment: I was thinking of using the first approach that you mentioned but curious if it's possible to do it via templateProvider. And thanks for that alternative solution, I'll definitely give it a try.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with uiRouter's templateProvider alone, no. I mean, you certainly could make it so the templateProvider does return alternating results, but it can't do anything on its own to cause the template to reload, so you would still have to force the state to reload to achieve the effect. In any case though I would suggest that using a directive/controller solution to achieve this effect will provide better logical separation and is the much more ... "angular" approach.